# Método no p:commandButton não é chamado

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, primefaces-3.5

Na minha view tem p:commandButton com um método que adiciona um item a um p:dataTable. Ao clicar no botão para chamar o método para adicionar o primeiro item, ele é adicionado corretamente ao dataTable, mas ao clicar no botão para adicionar outro item, o método simplesmente não é mais chamado. Além disso, os p:ajax que tem na view também param de funcionar e nenhum erro aparece no console. O curioso é que algumas vezes que eu testo funciona e outras não.

**View**

[Código da View no Paste Bin](https://pastebin.com/802zCCrM)

**Método Adicionar no Controller**

```
public void adicionar() {              
   if(diasSemanaSelecionados != null) {
       responsabilidadeTecnica.setDiasSemana(Arrays.asList(diasSemanaSelecionados));
   }

   responsabilidadeTecnica.setHorarioTrabalho(s);      
   responsabilidadeTecnica.setFimContrato(null);
   responsabilidadesTecnicas.add(responsabilidadeTecnica);

   renderizaAdicionarResponsavelTecnico = false;
 }
```